# Getting Colored pixels of humanStencilTexture from ARHumanBodyManger

Tags: unity-game-engine, arkit, texture2d

I am creating an AR application for iOs using Unity and ARKit 3.

I am using People occlusion sample to detect human bodies.

ARHumanBodyManger has a property called humanStencilTexture which return Texture2D which preview the human body in red and other things in black as shown in this image.

[image]

I want to identify the coloured pixels in this Texture.

I used `humanStencilTexture.GetPixels()` to get all pixels and when I checked these pixels they all black.

Can anyone help me how to check for red pixels?

Comment: ```humanStencilTexture.GetPixels()``` is this an array of bites?

Comment: It returns an array of Colors